# How to load the file data to download template on page refresh in blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp, multi-upload

Similar to this question: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1466

everytime on page load, how do i load download template with file data by default? seem to be no answer in google.

thanks.

Comment: Link in initial question dead

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and check you url for display images. In my case I am using "/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx".

This code you put in main.js.

```
$(function () {
        'use strict';

        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload();

        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            maxFileSize: 500000000,
            resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
            resizeMaxHeight: 1200
        });

        // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload(
            'option',
            'redirect',
            window.location.href.replace(
                /\/[^\/]*$/,
                '/cors/result.html?%s'
            )
        );

        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: "/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx",
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), { result: result });
        });
    });
```

Comment: just remember to send the response with the correct json format https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/JSON-Response and all shoul be all right

Answer (score 0):

I just did it with another stupid way. Not sure if is the real solution but it solve my problem temporarily.

what i've done as below,

1. check database if photos data available in table.
2. if return true, i will show the upload template (copy from the default script in blueimp)

for example:

```
<?php 
                if($imageResults != false){                      
                    //show image
                    while($imageRow=mysqli_fetch_array($imageResults))
                    {
                        echo '<div class="template-download fade in" style="float:left; display:inline-block; margin: 0 10px 10px;">
    <div>
        <span class="preview">

                <a href="/upload/server/php/files/"'.$imageRow['name'].'" title="'.$imageRow['name'].'" download="'.$imageRow['name'].'" data-gallery=""><img src="/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/'.$imageRow['name'].'"></a>

        </span>
    </div>
    <div>

            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="POST" data-url="/upload/server/php/?file='.$imageRow['name'].'&amp;_method=DELETE">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">

    </div>
</div>';
                    }
                }
                //else leave blank
            ?>
```

with this by default it will load download template with file.